# Unable to load specified config location file on GGTS

Tags: grails, web-applications, ggts

When I "run on Server" my web app using ggts I get a 404 and in my console the following error:

```
   Unable to load specified config location file:./grails-app/conf/app-config.properties .\grails-app\conf\app-config.properties (Impossible to find the specified path)
```

the `app-config.properties` is under the folder **conf** of my app

Please note that if I use `grails run-app`, it works properly and run my app so the problem is definitely on my ggts 3.6.4.RELEASE.

if I go to **http://localhost:8080/** the server home page is displayed.

in my Server View, the app appears started and my Problems View does not show anything.

grails version is 1.3.7

Please How to fix it or how can I investigate further?

Comment: couple of things you may check. is the config file copied to the server under the location mentioned? how did you configure the server in ggts? have a look at the run configurations.
[This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180299/troubleshoot-eclipses-run-on-server-deploy) may give you some hints.

Comment: I am using Pivotal

Comment: what should I check in the run conf.?

Comment: Which version of Grails? Did you try to load it from different location for example via system specified variable?

Comment: grails version is 1.3.7